# Execute last command(s) in OpenSSH Client on Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, powershell, openssh

I'm using OpenSSH Client shipped with Windows 10 (Home) through the Powershell. How do i repeat the last command(s)? I was used to using the up key to browse throught the last executed commands, but that doesn't work, using any arrow key results in stange characters showing up in the command line ( i.e. ^[[A ).
Other Linux related commands, like !!, also don't work... any idea?

EDIT: The problem seems to be Server side (Unbuntu) and not the OpenSSH Client on Windows (the same probelm occurs with Putty). So the question now is: how do I activate last command with key up and auto-completion with tab on the remote server.

Comment: `ssh -V` in Windows PowerShell gives me `OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5`, when connected it gives me `OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017` I did not try other SSH clients, my machine is limited to what I can autonomously install...

Comment: I've managed to launch putty but thave same problem, up keys and tab completion do not work. Could it be a server side problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you may have a `sh` shell as a default instead of `bash`. `sh` has very limited command line editing capabilities and does not support recalling previous commands with up/down arrows.

To check this, type the following command:

```
grep '^username:' /etc/passwd
```

where you should of course replace *username* with your actual username that you use in Linux system.

You should see a line like this (in my case):

```
raj:x:1000:1000:Jarek,,,:/home/raj:/bin/bash
```

Your default shell is shown at the end of the line. If it's `/bin/bash` like above, up/down arrows should work. If they don't work, someone must have messed something up in the shell startup scripts (usually `.profile` and `.bashrc` files).

If your shell is different from `/bin/bash` (for example `/bin/sh`) you may try to change it. Type the command `chsh` (it will ask for your password) and type `/bin/bash` as the new shell. After you log in in a new session, your new shell should be active.

Comment: That did it! I actually had `/bin/sh`, changed it to `bin/bash` and now recalling previous commands through arrow keys and tab completion work. Thanks Raj!